# MySQL Leaderboard view

Tags: mysql, view, leaderboard

I have a table with the following data

```
USER_ID | REVENUE
1  | 12,545
2  | 9,845
3  | 55,874
```

Is there a way for me to create a result with ranking on the fly within a view i.e.

```
USER_ID | REVENUE | RANK
3  |   55,874  |  1
1  |   12,545  |  2
2  |   9,845   |  3
```

I could try doing this by running a cron, but would like the result to be real-time - generated by MySQL in a view.

Any other alternatives welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but as two separate queries:

```
select @last:=0;

select USER_ID, REVENUE, @RANK := @RANK + 1 as RANK
from YOURTABLE
order by ...
```

Comment: problem doing it this way is that MySQL Views cannot use variables or parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done in one query

```
select user_id, 
       revenue, 
       @rank := rank + 1 as rank
from your_table, (select @rank := 0) r
order by revenue desc
```